Neovim Vim - stylua is not executable (make sure it's installed and on your $PATH)
I am trying to setup neovim and I am getting following error in my NullLsLog
plugin/null-ls.lua
return {
  "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim",
  event = { "BufReadPre", "BufNewFile" },
  dependencies = { "mason.nvim" },
  config = function()
    require("null-ls").setup({
      debug = true,
    })
  end,
  opts = function()
    return require "custom.configs.null-ls"
  end,
}

config/null-ls.lua
local augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("lspformatting", {})
local null_ls = require("null-ls")

local opts = {
  sources = {
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.black,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua,
    -- null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.mypy,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.terraform_fmt,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.shellharden,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettier.with({ filetypes = { "json" } }),
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.isort,
    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.pylint.with({ prefer_local = ".venv/bin", },
      { extra_args = { "--disable=C0114,C0115,C0116" } }),
    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.terraform_validate,
  },
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    if client.supports_method("textdocument/formatting") then
      vim.api.nvim_clear_autocmds({
        group = augroup,
        buffer = bufnr
      })
      vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("bufwritepre", {
        group = augroup,
        buffer = bufnr,
        callback = function()
          vim.lsp.buf.format({
            buffer = bufnr,
            async = false,
            filter = function(client)
              return client.name == "null-ls"
            end
          })
        end,
      })
    end
  end
}
return opts

I am installing binaries through mason.
plugins/mason.lua
return {
  "williamboman/mason.nvim",
  opts = {
    ensure_installed = {
      "pyright",
      "mypy",
      "pylint",
      -- "flake8", -- removed in latest version of nulls ls
      "ruff",
      "black",
      "debugpy",
      "terraform-ls",
      "lua-language-server",
      "fixjson",
      "shellharden",
      "prettier",
      "isort",
      "stylua"
    },
  },
}


Am I missing something or there is no actual error in the question?
